# How to use igraph python's metamagic class?

Tags: python, igraph

The python interface of `igraph` has a class called `metamagic`, serving the purpose to collect graphical parameters for plotting. I am writing a module using igraph, and I almost started to write my own wrapper functions for this purpose, when I've found metamagic in the documentation. But after searching and trying, it's still not clear how to use these classes. If I define an `AttributeCollectorBase` class for edges, like this:

```
class VisEdge(igraph.drawing.metamagic.AttributeCollectorBase):
    width = 0.002
    color = "#CCCCCC44"
```

Then, is there an easy way to pass all these parameters to the `igraph.plot()` function? Or I can only do one by one, like this: `plot(graph,edge_color=VisEdge(graph.es).color)`?
And what if I would like to use not constant parameters, but calculate by a custom function? For example, `vertex_size` proportional to degree. The `func` parameter of the `AttributeSpecification` class supposed to do this, isn't it? But I haven't seen any example how to use it. If I define an `AttributeSpecification` instance, like this:

```
ds = igraph.drawing.metamagic.AttributeSpecification(name="vertex_size",alt_name="size",default=2,func='degree')
```

After how to pass it to an `AtributeCollector`, and finally to `plot()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(To put things in context: I am the author of the Python interface of igraph).

I'm not sure whether the `metamagic` package is the right tool for you. The only purpose of the `AttributeCollectorBase` class is to allow the vertex and edge drawers in igraph (see the `igraph.drawing.vertex` and `igraph.drawing.edge` packages) to define what vertex and edge attributes they are able to treat as visual properties in a nice and concise manner (without me having to type too much). So, for instance, if you take a look at the `DefaultVertexDrawer` class in `igraph.drawing.vertex`, you can see that I construct a `VisualVertexBuilder` class by deriving it from `AttributeCollectorBase` as follows:

```
class VisualVertexBuilder(AttributeCollectorBase):
    """Collects some visual properties of a vertex for drawing"""
    _kwds_prefix = "vertex_"
    color = ("red", self.palette.get)
    frame_color = ("black", self.palette.get)
    frame_width = 1.0
    ...
```

Later on, when the `DefaultVertexDrawer` is being used in `DefaultGraphDrawer`, I simply construct a `VisualVertexBuilder` as follows:

```
vertex_builder = vertex_drawer.VisualVertexBuilder(graph.vs, kwds)
```

where `graph.vs` is the vertex sequence of the graph (so the vertex builder can get access to the vertex attributes) and `kwds` is the set of keyword arguments passed to `plot()`. The `vertex_builder` variable then allows me to retrieve the calculated, effective visual properties of vertex `i` by writing something like `vertex_builder[i].color`; here, it is the responsibility of the `VisualVertexBuilder` to determine the effective color by looking at the vertex and checking its `color` attribute as well as looking at the keyword arguments and checking whether it contains `vertex_color`.

The bottom line is that the `AttributeCollectorBase` class is likely to be useful to you only if you are implementing a custom graph, vertex or edge drawer and you want to specify which vertex attributes you wish to treat as visual properties. If you only want to plot a graph and derive the visual properties of that particular graph from some other data, then `AttributeCollectorBase` is of no use to you. For instance, if you want the size of the vertex be proportional to the degree, the preferred way to do it is either this:

```
sizes = rescale(graph.degree(), out_range=(0, 10))
plot(graph, vertex_size=sizes)
```

or this:

```
graph.vs["size"] = rescale(graph.degree(), out_range=(0, 10))
plot(g)
```

If you have many visual properties, the best way is probably to collect them into a dictionary first and then pass that dictionary to `plot()`; e.g.:

```
visual_props = dict(
    vertex_size = rescale(graph.degree(), out_range=(0, 10)),
    edge_width = rescale(graph.es["weight"], out_range=(0, 5), scale=log10)
)
plot(g, **visual_props)
```

Take a look at the documentation of the `rescale` function for more details. If you want to map some vertex property into the color of the vertex, you can still use `rescale` to map the property into the range 0-255, then round them to the nearest integer and use a palette when plotting:

```
palette = palettes["red-yellow-green"]
colors = [round(x) for x in rescale(g.degree(), out_range=(0, len(palette)-1))]
plot(g, vertex_color=colors, palette=palette)
```

Comment: So I misunderstood the metamagic module, and probably it's not for me. Thank you Tamás for the detailed answer, and for the useful hints on the `rescale` function!